# Oracle query not giving result for current_date

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

What is the query in Oracle to fetch the data for current_date 
the column end_date is like the following

```
end_date
27-10-16 03:35:00.000000000 PM
23-11-16 11:15:00.000000000 AM
02-11-16 03:00:00.000000000 PM
08-11-16 09:00:00.000000000 AM
```

Like I am running the following query as

```
Select * from table1
where end_date < TO_DATE('2017-04-11 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

it is running successfully, but when i replace the query with the current date ... it is not giving the results

```
Select * from table1
where end_date < TO_DATE(current_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

could someone tell me what is the cause the second query is not giving results.

Comment: ***NEVER*** call `to_date()` on a value that is already a `date`. It will convert the `date` to  a `varchar` just to convert it back to a `date` which it was to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query worked like this :

```
Select * from table1
    where trunc(end_date) < trunc(sysdate)
```

Trunc is used to compare the both dates  and it fetch the results.

Comment: `trunc` removes the time part in a date. Nothing more.

Comment: @Nitesh sysdate is comparing according to the time and removing the time part give the actual result, trunc is helpful.

Comment: But with the data given in the question, even if you omit `trunc` it'll work.

Comment: @Nitesh No it is not working when we omit trunc ... It is working in few comparisions like > and < but not in equal to ... for = and other relational operators, it is working with Trunc..

Comment: Then both the date parts will be same, only the time parts will be different.

Answer (score 2):

`CURRENT_DATE` returns date. There is no need to use `TO_DATE`. The below query should be enough.

```
Select * from table1
  where end_date < current_date;
```

If you run the below query you'll understand what went wrong for you. Year becomes 0011.

```
SELECT TO_DATE(current_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL;
```

Please note that `CURRENT_DATE` returns the current date in the session time zone. `SYSDATE` returns the current date and time set for the operating system on which the database resides. This means that `CURRENT_DATE` and `SYSDATE` can return different results. You can have a look at [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/ecmarch/entry/be_aware_of_the_difference)

Answer (score 0):

`CURRENT_DATE` is already a `DATE` value. You can format the output using `to_char` if you want.

`end_date < CURRENT_DATE` should do the job. Or you can set the nls parameter accordingly for a better readability.

If you are comparing only date, without timestamp, you can go with `trunc()`

Comment: Thanks for the info